# How to use the uc_csv module for getting reports

Tags: 7, ubercart, importing-exporting

I am using the ubercart module for purchasing products. I want to export the order records/history as csv file and view it in spreadsheet. So I searched and got the uc_csv module. I have installed the module for Drupal 7. When I click the `csv export` link from store administration option it shows:

> "THERE ARE CURRENTLY NO CONFIGURED EXPORT REPORTS".

How can I configure this option? Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: Look for the tab that says "CREATE NEW REPORT." After you set that up, you can export reports.

Answer (score 0):

you can create export reports by clicking the "CSV Export" menu item located under "Store administration" in the Drupal administrative menu system.

You can create any number of reports to export certain criteria. More granular criteria can be programmed later if there is demand for such a feature. Please provide feedback if this is the case.

Comment: Hi monymirza, Did you understand my question? While clicking "CSV Export" it shows nothing and there is no link for creating reports, then how will i create a report? Plz give some other ideas.

Comment: do have any order history? if not, then how can reports get?

Comment: Order history in the sense, we can view the orders through orders link from store administration option. It may be the order history.